# Properties of the power set of $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

Let $A$ be any set . Let $\wp(A)$ be the power set of $A$. Then which of the following are true

1) $\wp(A) = \emptyset$ for some $A$

2) $\wp(A) $ is a finite set for  some $A$

3) $\wp(A)$ is a countable set for some $A$.

4) $\wp(A)$ is uncountable for some set $A$

for 1) take $A= \emptyset$, then $\wp(A) = \emptyset$.

for 2) take $A$ is a finite set, then $\wp(A)$ is a finite set.

for 3) If $A$ is finite then  $\wp(A)$ is a finite set, if $A$ is infinite , then $\wp(A)$ is uncountable set. I think this is false.

for 4) Take $A = \mathbb N$, then $\wp(A)$ is uncountable.

This is an exam problem . I would be thankful if someone check my problem, if feel any error then correct.

Comment: 2 and 4 are the only true ones.  For 1, $P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$, which is the set CONTAINING the empty set.  Your reasoning for the rest is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (1), $\wp(\emptyset)$ **is not equal to** $\emptyset$, because $\wp(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$. The set $\{\emptyset\}$ **is not** an empty set, because the set $\{\emptyset\}$ contains *one element*, and that element is $\emptyset$.

For (2), you are correct, but you need to *prove* that is the case.

For (3) again, you have the right idea, but you need to prove it. To prove it, I suggest you prove that if $A$ is infinite, it contains a countable subset, and the power set of $A$ must contain the power set of the countable subset.

For (4), you are correct, and if you have proven in lectures that $\wp(a)$ is uncountable, this is enough. Otherwise, you need to prove it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: @5xum 3rd option is right or wrong?

Comment: @neelkanth If you define countable as "equipotent to $\mathbb N$", then wrong.

Comment: @5xum   its means its wrong option from exam point of view???

Comment: @neelkanth Yes. No power set can be countable. It is either finite or uncountable.

Comment: @5xum ok thanks a lot....